# Why YOLOv3 calculate the offset values for adjusting the anchor boxes, not directly output the dimension of the bounding box?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying to understand about how YOLOv3 works. And this thing still confuses me: YOLO can determine the bounding box (the coordinates and dimensions), but why it doesn't output these value directly, instead of using them to adjust the anchor boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most object detection algorithms compute offset (x, y, width, height) for bounding boxes compared to a fixed anchor.

Anchors are generally generated to follow a fix grid: for each location on the grid a set of anchors of different aspect ratios and different areas are created.

It's much easier for the learning algorithm to output an offset from the fixed anchor from which it can deduce the overall coordinate rather than trying to find the overall coordinate directly because it's a local and position-invariant feature.

It means that if there is a dog with a mis-centered bounding box on the top-left of the picture, the algorithm is asked to output the offset as if the dog were on the bottom-right of the picture, which makes it robust to shift and does not require it to learn the global position of the object in the image.